# label for[...] not recognised by IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have the css below:

```
span label[for=Length]
{
width: 90px; 
display: block;
text-align:right; 
margin-top: 2px;
margin-right: 5px;
}
```

with the html:

```
<span><label for="Length">Length:</label></span>
<span><input type=text id="Length"></span>
```

It doesn't work in IE8. **label[for=...]** is not recognised. Any workaround?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE

I do a mistake in my question so now I updated. Any solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE 8 (or IE 9 for that matter) does not support attribute selectors in [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html). This is why adding a suitable doctype declaration, as suggested in Quentin’s answer, fixes the issue on IE 8. The simplest doctype for the purpose is `<!doctype html>`.

On IE 7, nothing helps, as it simply lacks the support, instead of having it masked out in Quirks Mode.

It is thus safer to use an `id` attribute on the `label` element, e.g. `<label id=foo for=Length>`, and use an `id` selector, such as `#foo`, in CSS. Such selectors work on all CSS-enabled browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `<label>` element with a `for="Length"` attribute.

(And make sure you have a Doctype that triggers Standards Mode)

Comment: Sorry I mistake my html code. I updated my question to show the right html code.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the doctype but the problem in IE7 is still there.

Answer (score 3):

The element has to be a label in order to be able to match it as a label in css try this:

```
<label for="Length">Length:</label>
<span><input type=text id="Length"></span>
```

Comment: Sorry I mistake my html code. I updated my question to show the right html code.

Answer (score 0):

```
.label1
{
width: 90px; 
display: block;
text-align:right; 
margin-top: 2px;
margin-right: 5px;
}

<span>Length:</span>
<label class='label1' for='Length'><input type=text id="Length"></label>
```

Answer (score -1):

It works in IE8.. Not depends on the browser. Check the !doctype html for the file. Hence its an attribute, it works.

Comment: Maybe it should be a comment ?

Comment: Yeah but he is not asking whether it's working for you or not, he is asking for a workaround. So it should be a comment.