# Checkbox click event also executed when clicking the label

Tags: jquery

I was wondering why the checkbox click event executed when clicking the label. Any help please how to prevent executing when clicking on the label

//Click event

//I try this one

```
 $("input:checkbox[name*='chkFields']").click(function (evt) {
        if ($(evt.target).is("input")) {
            if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked") {
}}});
```

//And also this one

```
$("input:checkbox[name*='chkFields']").click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked") {
         logic here....
}
});
```

// HTML

```
<div class="FloatLeft" id="draggableElements">

               <div style="width: auto!important; margin-bottom: 0px;" class="TableCellHeader metooltip ellipsis" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_sbMain_ctl01_sbGroups_ctl01_DraggableListID_repColumnCategory_ctl00_divHeader" title="
                   Employee 

               ">
                   Employee 
               </div>
               <div style="margin-bottom:5px">
                   <table class="checkbox" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_sbMain_ctl01_sbGroups_ctl01_DraggableListID_repColumnCategory_ctl00_chkFields">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <span class="aspNetDisabled">
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" value="106" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderContent$sbMain$ctl01$sbGroups$ctl01$DraggableListID$repColumnCategory$ctl00$chkFields$0" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_sbMain_ctl01_sbGroups_ctl01_DraggableListID_repColumnCategory_ctl00_chkFields_0" style="visibility: hidden;">
                                                                    <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_sbMain_ctl01_sbGroups_ctl01_DraggableListID_repColumnCategory_ctl00_chkFields_0">Employee Name</label>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <span>
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" value="20" checked="checked" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderContent$sbMain$ctl01$sbGroups$ctl01$DraggableListID$repColumnCategory$ctl00$chkFields$1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_sbMain_ctl01_sbGroups_ctl01_DraggableListID_repColumnCategory_ctl00_chkFields_1">
                                                                    <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_sbMain_ctl01_sbGroups_ctl01_DraggableListID_repColumnCategory_ctl00_chkFields_1">Job</label>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <span>
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" value="21" checked="checked" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderContent$sbMain$ctl01$sbGroups$ctl01$DraggableListID$repColumnCategory$ctl00$chkFields$2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_sbMain_ctl01_sbGroups_ctl01_DraggableListID_repColumnCategory_ctl00_chkFields_2">
                                                                    <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_sbMain_ctl01_sbGroups_ctl01_DraggableListID_repColumnCategory_ctl00_chkFields_2">Age</label>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody></table>
               </div>

               <div style="width: auto!important; margin-bottom: 0px;" class="TableCellHeader metooltip ellipsis" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_sbMain_ctl01_sbGroups_ctl01_DraggableListID_repColumnCategory_ctl01_divHeader" title="
                   Sample text

               ">
                   Sample text
               </div>
               <div style="margin-bottom:5px">
                   <table class="checkbox" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_sbMain_ctl01_sbGroups_ctl01_DraggableListID_repColumnCategory_ctl01_chkFields">
                                                        <tbody><tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <input type="checkbox" value="89" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderContent$sbMain$ctl01$sbGroups$ctl01$DraggableListID$repColumnCategory$ctl01$chkFields$0" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_sbMain_ctl01_sbGroups_ctl01_DraggableListID_repColumnCategory_ctl01_chkFields_0">
                                                                <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_sbMain_ctl01_sbGroups_ctl01_DraggableListID_repColumnCategory_ctl01_chkFields_0">Amount</label>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <input type="checkbox" value="90" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderContent$sbMain$ctl01$sbGroups$ctl01$DraggableListID$repColumnCategory$ctl01$chkFields$1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_sbMain_ctl01_sbGroups_ctl01_DraggableListID_repColumnCategory_ctl01_chkFields_1">
                                                                <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_sbMain_ctl01_sbGroups_ctl01_DraggableListID_repColumnCategory_ctl01_chkFields_1">Percent</label></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <input type="checkbox" value="91" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderContent$sbMain$ctl01$sbGroups$ctl01$DraggableListID$repColumnCategory$ctl01$chkFields$2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_sbMain_ctl01_sbGroups_ctl01_DraggableListID_repColumnCategory_ctl01_chkFields_2">
                                                                <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_sbMain_ctl01_sbGroups_ctl01_DraggableListID_repColumnCategory_ctl01_chkFields_2">Adjustment</label>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody></table>
               </div>



 </div>
```

Comment: Simply don't use a label. The entire point of `<label>` is that you can toggle its corresponding checkbox by clicking on it. (Although I'm not sure why you would not want it to work that way.)

Comment: sorry the label was automatic created, because I am using checkboxlist control.

Comment: Well, again, why do you not want the label to work as it's designed to work? If you somehow manage to get the click event to work only on the checkbox itself, your script will break whenever someone toggles the checkbox by clicking on the label (the checkbox status changes but your event doesn't trigger).

Comment: Because it is not stated in the requirements. Only the checkbox was mentioned to execute when clicking it. If so, then is there a way to execute the click event of the label on IE browser without encountering any errors?I experiencing this today that when clicking on the label will encountering errors, the checkbox was not checked sometimes when clicking on it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it.

This is an accounted behavior for most people that doesn't have the dexterity to click in a really small squared box. Although, clicking in a well associated and descriptive label makes it infinitely easier.

Also, I'm pretty sure that it helps screen readers for visually impaired people.

Comment: OK, then how to execute when clicking the label on IE browsers, since it is not working when using click event? Is there a propertyclick event?

Comment: @user335160, this may help: [label's `for` not recognised by IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10176064/417685)

Answer (score 1):

I try to manage this one.
Here is the code snippets

```
 $("label[for*='chkFields']").click(function(ev) { ev.preventDefault(); });
```