# IE8 Label for and Knockout binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

I have a template with checkbox and label which bind with knockout 'for' attribute.

Not able to trigger click event, but It works in all the browser except IE8

```
 <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" data-bind="value:Id,checked:$root.selectedCategoryIds,attr: { 'id': 'product-choice-' + Id, name: Name }" />
 <label class="label-container" data-bind="attr: { 'for': IsEnabled ? 'product-choice-' + Id : '' }">                
            <span class="checkbox-icon" data-bind="visible:IsEnabled"></span>
            <span class="checkbox-label" data-bind="text:Name"></span>
 </label>
```

Even I've specified Doc standard.

Is there any workaround

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [label for\[...\] not recognised by IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176064/label-for-not-recognised-by-ie8)

Answer (score 0):

IE8 sometimes throws errors when unquoted attributes that are also reserved words in javascript (like `for`, `class`) are in the HTML (I had this with `class`). Therefore it is safest to quote your attributes in the `data-bind`, eg: `data-bind="attr: { 'for': 'mylabel, 'class': 'myclass' }"`. Make sure you use both `for` on the label and `name` & `id` on the input.

Also, when you use an observable (if you do) in an expression (`isEnabled` in your example above), you should execute it: `isEnabled()`, because else it will always return true.